# Firebase - Getting data from child sometimes returns unknown

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an Android app with React Native using Firebase to implement chat between users. I'm running tests now and found out that, on occasion, sending chat messages produces the following exception and crashes the app:

> Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

This is the function that sends messages to the Firebase Realtime Database, triggered whenever the "send message" button is pressed:

```
sendMessageToFirebase(chatId, userId){
  let newMessage = {created: new Date().toJSON(), text: this.state.textInput}
  //getting messages data from firebase
  let data = {};
  console.log('REF:' + firebase.database().ref('chats'));
  dataRef = firebase.database().ref('chats').child(chatId);
  console.log('REF WITH CHILD: ' + dataRef);
  dataRef.on('value', datasnap=>{
      data = datasnap.val()
      //the following function rewrites the dictionary fetched from FB to add the new message
      data = this.rewriteFirebaseChatData(data, userId, newMessage);
  })
  //sending the data
  dataRef.set(data)
  this.loadMessagesFromFirebase(chatId);
}
```

The first console log, with just the ref, will always print, but on a seemingly random basis, the second ref will not and I'll get the exception, so I can assume that's where the issue is. Is there a way to fetch data from the child reliably?

Comment: on the line where you have  "child(chatId)" where is chatId coming from check in your log if this variable is being passed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error comes from the code you shared, it seems that `chatId` is `undefined`.

You'll want to check in the calling code why that happens. If this is a valid case, you'll want to check for it in `sendMessageToFirebase` too, for example by adding this to the start of the method:

```
if (!chatId) return;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The chatId was not being set properly in the component's state.